# How to make permlink uppercase to lowercase

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo, permalinks

I successfully changes permlink with SEO URL but i'm facing problem with uppercase. I changed **detail.php** with `<a href="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $row['title']);?>`
 and Created .htaccess `

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.birthdaycakenames.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://birthdaycakenames.com/$1 [L,R=301]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
Options -Indexes
```

now i want to change uppercase url to lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Function in PHP

```
$Title = 'For Example Title';
function seoUrl($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
return $string;
}
echo seoUrl($Title);
```

Replace This Code 
`<?php echo seoUrl($row['title']);?>`

Comment: Use the Function in PHP